# Hybridization state of oxygen in carbonyl sulfide (COS)

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, orbitals, hybridization, valence-bond-theory

I've been scratching my head on this one for awhile here. In a carbonyl sulfide (COS) molecule, what is the hybridization state of oxygen?

Carbonyl sulfide is composed of a single carbon atom double bonded to oxygen and sulfur atoms. The sulfur and oxygen atoms each harbor two lone pairs.

[image]

**Looking at oxygen, I count electron-dense groups:**

- There is one bonded atom
- There are two lone pairs

This should amount to an sp<sup>2</sup> hybridized orbitals for oxygen, before exceptions are accounted for.

**Checking if any lone pairs are delocalized:**

- Oxygen both participates in a pi-bond and is adjacent to a carbon that participates in a pi-bond

This is where I'm stuck. Are any of oxygen's lone electron pairs delocalized due to these facts? Is the hybridized orbital not sp<sup>2</sup> for oxygen?

Comment: In between, though generally considered as sp2.

Comment: @AdityaRoychowdhury Maybe, but they shouldn't https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/80962/what-is-the-hybridization-of-terminal-fluorine-atoms-in-molecules-like-boron-tri