# Lone Pairs Hybridization

Tags: hybridization

Why are lone pairs considered when determining the hybridization orbitals of an atom? If the lone pairs will lead towards a filled orbital and won't perform any bonding, why can't they be left unhybridized?

Comment: They can, and often are. better described as unhybridized.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/80962/what-is-the-hybridization-of-terminal-fluorine-atoms-in-molecules-like-boron-tri