# When is it true that more nodes equals higher energy?

Tags: physical-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, orbitals, molecular-orbital-theory, symmetry

Consider all the MOs of some isolated molecule. (It could be a single
atom too; I'll use MO to refer to AOs as well.) Number them in
increasing order of the number of nodes (node = surface where the wave
function has zero density). Orbitals with the same number of nodes can
be numbered in any order. Now you have a sequence of orbitals $O_1,
O_2, ...$. Let their respective energies be $E_1, E_2, ...$.

It seems to be "common knowledge" that $E_n \le E_{n+1}$ for any such
system and any $n$. As Martin put it to me yesterday, "[An orbital
with 47 nodes can never be lower in energy than one with only 46](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15903/counting-nodal-planes-in-cyclopropane)." (Follow up on [Counting Nodal Planes in cyclopropane](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/14528/4945).)

For various reasons, given below, I think this cannot be true in
general, and I'd really like to know under what conditions it is
*known* to be true. "Known" here can mean either a rigorous statement
with a reference to a proof (a trivial example would be: It is true
for a one-electron atom; we can calculate the energies exactly) or a
precise statement with empirical justification (something like "no
counterexamples are known for class X of molecules" - again with a
reference).

*Important*: Please, I'm not looking for an explanation that re-states
the rule in some equivalent or even looser fashion ("more nodes means
the orbital is larger and less dense, therefore it must be higher in
energy").

---

Why do I think the statement can't be always true? Well, a calcium
atom has a filled 4s orbital and empty 3d orbitals. *If this does not
count as a counterexample, please explain what notion of orbital
energy the statement applies to.*

In general, I'm happy to believe that two MOs must satisfy the rule if
they have "comparable" sets of nodes (say, constant $n_x$ and $n_y$ in the
example I'm about to discuss), but I'd like to understand what is
meant by "comparable" in general. In a molecule with no symmetry, are
there comparable MOs at all? If so, how do we know if two given MOs
are comparable?

The case of a much simpler system, the 3D rectangular box, may
also be relevant.  The energy levels for such a box are of course
$$
\frac{\hbar^2\pi^2}{2m}\biggl(
\frac{n_x^2}{L_x^2}+
\frac{n_y^2}{L_y^2}+
\frac{n_z^2}{L_z^2}
\biggr),
$$
where $n_x$, $n_y$ and $n_z$ are one more (or one less, if you count
the walls) than the number of nodal planes in the respective
direction. If we take $L_x = L_y = 1$ and $L_z = 0.1$ (say), the
wavefunction with $n_x=5$, $n_y=1$, $n_z =1$ has energy $5^2+ 1^2 +
(1/0.1)^2 = 126$ and 4 nodes (or 10, if you count the walls), while
the wavefunction for $n_x=1$, $n_y=1$, $n_z=2$ has energy $402$ and 1
node (or 7). So clearly the rule is not true here.

Granted that molecules are not boxes, but this does show that
arguments based simply on the number of sign changes are not rigorous,
so they don't answer my question.

Comment: Martin - very generous of you to offer a bounty.  I too am puzzled that nobody has replied or made comments so far!

Comment: I really want a canonical answer myself. However, I believe you are correct and my previous assumption was too narrow minded. But I really would like to have a little more prove. And I know that there are people in this community that could give more insight.

Comment: Particle in a 3D box follows this rule where energy scales with nodes.  So does particle in a 1D box.  But that is because the waves you are comparing are comparable.  With the 3D rectangle with different values of L (for x, y, and z), you can only compare the x-, y-, and z- components with *each other*.  You can't sum over all the nodes and make this comparison.  Just like you can compare 1s, 2s, 3,s, etc. with each other, p-orbitals with each other, etc. but not p- and d- orbitals.  The correlation breaks down when you do that.

Comment: @LordStryker - thanks. Reply: "Particle in a 3D box follows this rule" -- By "THIS rule" you don't mean the rule I wrote but your rule: "you can only compare the x-, y-, and z- components with each other." Fair enough. But if drive a nail into the box and destroy the symmetry of this toy example you no longer have x-, y-, and z- modes.  So in this situation WHAT rule is followed?  Regarding "You can't sum over all the nodes and make this comparison." -- Again: Can you state what makes two nodes comparable, i.e, how one can tell that two nodes are comparable?

Comment: @SilvioLevy You bring up a good point.  I've never worked PIAB examples in anything other than the simple 1D/2D examples, cubes, and rectangles.  Particle in a 'funhouse'?  I'd love to see someone work out an example like that.

Comment: While we still have not received a nice answer here, we at least enhanced the awareness of the whole problem, which I think is a good thing. This might be a question, that will bother me from time and again. Just like the $\alpha$ effect one. http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/7460/4945

Comment: @SilvioLevy A counterexample to the assumption that more nodes lead to higher energy might be found in homonuclear diatomic molecules of elements that are heavier than $\ce{N}$. In those you have very little s,p-mixing and/or relatively little p,p-$\pi$-overlap. In such cases you get qualitatively the MO scheme shown [here](http://www.forgottenplanet.com/studyguide/chem210/ch3_3-28.jpg). There you can see that the $\sigma$ orbital formed by 2 p-orbitals is lower in energy than the $\pi$ orbitals formed by 2 p-orbitals. Yet the $\sigma$ orbital has 2 nodes whereas the $\pi$ orbital has only 1.

Comment: Well, thinking about my counterexample again, I'm not so sure anymore that it actually is a counterexample. Because the nodal planes of the 2 p-orbitals won't remain parallel in the $\sigma$-MO. It is likely that they bend towards each other. I'm not sure whether they will actually melt into one another above and below the bond mid and form some kind of oval-shaped nodal plane or whether they will bend towards each other in an asymptotical fashion meeting only at infinity (this second possibility seems to be more likely to me). Nevertheless, the example is not as clear cut as I thought.

Comment: Yes, the 3$\sigma_g$ < 1$\pi_u$ gives a counterexample, thank you. The alternative hypothesis would mean that the blue lobe is spatially bounded, i.e. there is a sphere outside of which the wavefunction has the same sign everywhere.  But this is only possible if is spherically symmetric.  I'll try to come up with a reference or a proof.

Comment: I appreciate, that this might not have been the answer we were looking for. I assigned the bounty anyways, since it gives at least some more information on the topic. We'll might have to revisit the whole thing in some time :D

Comment: Thank you very much!  I'm a newbie and wasn't sure who should assign the bounty, but I agree that Philipp's answer certainly deserves it.

Answer (score 28):

### General case

There is indeed a mathematical theorem that deals with the number of nodes an eigenfunction corresponding to a certain eigenvalue can possess.
It was laid down by Courant$^{[1, 2]}$ and it states the following:

> Given the self-adjoint second order (partial) differential equation
>
> \begin{equation} \left(\hat{L} + \lambda \rho(\mathbf{x}) \right)
>  u(\mathbf{x}) = 0 \end{equation}
>
> (where $\hat{L} = L(\mathbf{\Delta}, \mathbf{x})$ is a linear,
>   hermitian differential operator, $\rho(\mathbf{x})$ is positive and
>   bounded, and $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue) for a domain $G$ with
>   homogeneous boundary conditions, that is $u(\mathbf{x}) = 0$ on the
>   boundary of the region $G$; if its eigenfunctions are  ordered
>   according to increasing eigenvalues, then the nodes of the $n^{\text{th}}$ 
>   eigenfunction divide the domain into no more than $n$ subdomains. The
>   nodal set of $u(\mathbf{x})$ is defined as the set of points
>   $\mathbf{x}$ such that $u(\mathbf{x}) = 0$. No assumptions are made
>   about the number of independent variables.

The proof is rather involved and so I won't show it here. But if you want you can look it up in [1] or [here](http://www.civil.uwaterloo.ca/ggladwell/GW-Zhu1b.pdf).

So, Courant's nodal line theorem tells us, that if we order the possible energy eigenvalues of the time-independent Schroedinger equation as $\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 \leq \lambda_3 \leq \dots$, then (depending on precisely how you set up the numbering) the  $n^{\text{th}}$ eigenfunction, $\Psi_{n}$ (the one with energy eigenvalue $\lambda_n$) has **at most** $n$ nodes (including the trivial one at the boundary $\mathbf{x} \to \infty$). 
Unfortunately, this gives you only an upper bound for the number of nodes a wave function with a certain energy eigenvalue may possess. So, all we know is that the ground state wave function $\Psi_{1}$ cannot have any nodes within the region $G$ (in total it has one node, namely the one at $\mathbf{x} \to \infty$). Wave functions for higher $n$ may possess up to $n-1$ nodes within $G$ but may as well have less. Thus, we cannot in general say that if a wave function has more nodes than another one it will automatically correspond to a state with higher energy.

### Special case: Schroedinger equation in one dimension

There is however a special case:
For the [Sturm-Liouville eigenvalue problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory) (and thus for **ordinary second order differential equations** with homogeneous boundary conditions) we can strengthen Courant's nodal line theorem such that if we order the possible eigenvalues as $\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 \leq \lambda_3 \leq \dots$, then the  $n^{\text{th}}$ eigenfunction (the one with energy eigenvalue $\lambda_n$) has **exactly** $n$ nodes (including the trivial one at the boundary $\mathbf{x} \to \infty$).

This is useful since the one-dimensional time-independent Schrödinger equation is a special case of a Sturm-Liouville equation. So, in the case of the inhomogeneous radial Schrödinger equation with a local potential and node-less inhomogeneity such as the radial Schrödinger equation for the hydrogenic atom

\begin{equation}
\bigg( \frac{ - \hbar^{2} }{ 2 m_{\mathrm{e}} } \frac{ \mathrm{d}^{2} }{ \mathrm{d} r^{2} } + \frac{ \hbar^{2} }{ 2 m_{\mathrm{e}} } \frac{ \ell (\ell + 1) }{ r^{2} }  - \frac{ Z e^{2} }{ 2 m_{\mathrm{e}} r } - E \bigg) r R(r) = 0
\end{equation}

it is generally true that a wavefunction with more (radial) nodes must always correspond to a state of higher energy than a wavefunction with less radial nodes. Also, it is clear that the wavefunctions of the one-dimensional particle-in-a-box must follow this rule. But for the three-dimensional particle-in-a-box this is not true anymore, since in that case the Schroedinger equation of the system is not an ordinary second-order differential equation but a partial-differential equation for which only the general version of Courant's nodal line theorem holds.

### Some concluding remarks

For real-world system like molecules or crystals the Schroedinger equation is a partial differential equation for which the special case outlined above doesn't apply so that only Courant's nodal line theorem in its general form holds which doesn't give a strict justification for the statement that more nodes mean higher energy. Yet it is very often observed that the number of nodes indeed increases with increasing energy.
The reason for this can be motivated in the following way: The kinetic energy $E_{\mathrm{kin}}$ of a state is proportional to $\int \Psi \Delta \Psi \, d^{3} r$. Via [Gauss's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_theorem) it can be shown that $\int \Psi \Delta \Psi \, d^{3} r \propto \int |\nabla \Psi |^{2} \, d^{3} r$ and so $E_{\mathrm{kin}} \propto \int | \nabla \Psi |^{2} d^{3} r$. Now, nodes force a wavefunction to change it's sign. This often means that the value of $\Psi$ has to increase/decrease rather rapidly thus leading to areas with high absolute values of the gradient and thus to high kinetic energy. Since the potential energies shouldn't differ too much between the different states the higher kinetic energy usually also entails a higher total energy. As an example consider the bonding and antibonding wavefunctions of a homonuclear diatomic molecule whose atoms are placed at the positions $r_{\mathrm{A}}$ and $r_{\mathrm{B}}$.

[image]

The bonding wavefunction has no nodes. Its value between the atoms doesn't have to undergo a rapid change and thus the slope is rather low. The antibonding wavefunction has one node between the atoms. Its value between the atoms must change rapidly from its positive to its negative maximum thus entailing a very high slope. The slopes of the tail regions are comparable for the bonding and antibonding wavefunctions since it can smoothly fall of to zero at infinity and is not required to go from a maximum value to zero within a very confined region of space - thus even if one wavefunction has to start of at a higher maximum value the gradient will not be much higher. It follows that the antibonding wavefunction has a higher kinetic energy than the bonding wavefunction.

### References

[1] R. Courant, D. Hilbert, *Methods of Mathematical Physics*, Vol. 1, Interscience, New York, **1953**, p. 451-455.

[2] R. Courant, "Ein allgemeiner Satz zur Theorie der Eigenfunktionen Selbstadjungierter Differentialausdrücke", *Nachr. v. d. Ges. d. Wiss. zu Göttingen* **1923**, p. 81.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Philipp.  Courant's theorem is beautiful but it's far weaker than the general claim, since usually in  dimension d > 1 the number of eigenwaves with n nodes seems to grow roughly with $n^d$.   I was hoping there might be some rigorous results that have practical use.  Your concluding remarks are quite interesting but again the intuitive justification seems to be rigorous only in 1D. Also your first comment to the question provides a counterexample when the symmetries differ, even for homonuclear 2-atom systems.

Comment: Another question for @Philipp: IIRC the hypotheses of Courant's theorem are satisfied by the time-independent, nonrelativistic Schrödinger equation, but not by relativistic versions such as the Klein-Gordon equation.  Is this right, or am I confused?

Comment: @SilvioLevy I fear you can't do better than Courant's theorem. It strongly suggests that it is simply not generally true that more nodes mean higher energy. But the connection between kinetic energy and gradient of the wavefunction gives some justification why it is true most of the time. How much more practical use would you want?

Comment: @SilvioLevy Also, why do you think that my intuitive justification is only rigorous in 1D? It involves the gradient, not the first derivative. I only chose a 1D example because it was easier to visualize.

Comment: "How much more practical use would you want?" Something that allows you to make a prediction in a case of interest, or even some kind of statistical measure -- you say "most of the time" but I don't see how your argument  that "more nodes means higher kinetic energy" justifies that (if it were really true it would be true all the time; if it's true under some conditions, I'm looking for the conditions; apart from that I don't understand what it means for it to be true "most of the time").

Comment: "why do you think that my intuitive justification is only rigorous in 1D" - because the consequence of the justification fails in d>1, that being the whole point of my question.

Comment: @SilvioLevy Ah, I see. I'm not a mathematician by profession (not at all), so I'm certainly not up to date with developments on that topic. Maybe there are some stronger theorems for "practical" Schroedinger equations, but I haven't heard of them. As for "the consequence of the justification fails in d>1": the proportionality between kinetic energy and $|\nabla \Psi |^{2}$ should be sound. But of course potential energy might play a bigger role in some cases, so the consequence for the total energy is a bit handwaving - that's true.

Comment: To be clear, the issue is the $E_{\mathrm{kin}} \propto |\nabla\Psi |^{2}$, which should have an integral on the right side. You could have high $|\nabla \Psi|$ in a small region only, and still get a lower overall energy than on another wavefunction with slightly lower $|\nabla\Psi|$ over a larger region.

Comment: @SilvioLevy Oh, yes. Sorry, I was sloppy there. Of course there should be integrals. I will change this in my answer.

Comment: Thats something I think about as well on occasion. Maybe one can drive the intuition a bit further. Consider $d=3$ in central symmetric fields. Here symmetry helps to conjecture that in such cases one might partition the wave functions into families (of course now corresponding to irreps). Then one think about if the relation holds *within* each family. Another way to see it is that the we have three degrees of freedom to distribute nodal planes, that will somehow find an appropriate symmetry adaption.

Comment: However its plausible that between different families there will confusion of the energy ordering v.s. number of nodes. Another educating toy model in that sense, might be a particle in a 3D box with different edge-lengths $a,b,c$.  In that context it would be much fun to see if there are deeper functional relations within a family, like a ladder-up/down generator, be it only some approximate ones ....