# Do multielectron atoms have nodes?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, atoms, electrons, orbitals

For hydrogen, other than in the 1s state, the electron wavefunctions have radial and/or angular nodes where the electron probability density is zero.

In helium or further atoms with more than one electron, considering correlation of electrons, what happens to these nodes?  Are there still radial and angular nodes where electron probability density is zero?

For example, if helium is in a 2s2s state, is there anywhere that an electron cannot be?

Comment: If you haven't already seen it, [this answer of mine](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/14825/189) might be of interest to you. Maybe I'm overlooking something but this question might be rather difficult to answer. For one thing it will depend on which "kind" of wavefunction you mean. If you are talking about the many-particle wavefunctions then I think it is very difficult to say something definite about the nodal structure. But if you are talking about one-particle states, like Hartree-Fock or Kohn-Sham orbitals, then much more can be said.

Comment: For Kohn-Sham orbitals the sperical symmetry of an atom should always permit us to seperate the orbital into a spherical harmonic (whose nodes we are familiar with) and a radial component, which should have $n-l-1$ nodes.

Comment: Technically, wavefunction nodes for atomic orbitals only exist in solutions for the non-relativistic Schrödinger equation. Addition of relativistic terms means every region has a non-zero wavefunction value for every orbital; what used to be nodes then becomes "quasi-nodes".

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto As far as I know there exists a nodal line theorem for the radial component of the Dirac equation that gives the number of nodes for $r \in (0, \infty)$. It can be shown, that the number of nodes for the Large Component is $n - l - 1$ (the same as for the Schroedinger equation) and that the Small Component has either the same number of nodes as the Large Component or 1 additional node.

Comment: @Philipp I guess to make my question more specific, if helium is in a 2s2s state, is there anywhere that an electron cannot be?

Comment: @DavePhD I'll refer to my linked answer above: For multielectron atoms the general form of Courants nodal line theorem applies. Interestingly, one of its consequences is that the ground state wavefunction will never have a node. For excited states (such as your helium example) the matter is different: Here Courants theorem doesn't give a definite answer only an upper bound, so it might or might not contain nodes. And I think this is the answer to your question, you can't make a general statement and it might depend on the multielectron system at hand whether there are nodes or not.

Comment: @Philipp Clearly you have far greater knowledge than I on the physical foundation of atomic theory, so I'll gladly defer to your expertise. I do remember however reading something about relativistic orbitals being nodeless in a book or article, but that was two and a half years ago, so I can't remember it too well and I'm not sure I'd be able to pull up the source. Sorry I couldn't be of any use.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto I think you do me too much honor here :) My knowledge about relativistic quantum mechanics is actually very limited. It is only that a friend of mine wrote his master thesis about this subject and within this thesis I found a passage about the nodes of the **radial** Dirac equation. It might well be that relativistic orbitals in general do not have nodes. Also my statement was concerned with a spherically symmetric system and the resulting 1D radial Dirac equation. Maybe the source you mentioned considered other cases than this rather specific one.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto "according to Dirac’s relativistic treatment of an electron, which has now been extended to many-electron atoms, atomic orbitals possess no nodes whatsoever." http://www.chem.ucla.edu/dept/Faculty/scerri/pdf/Atkins_critique.pdf Foundations of Chemistry 1: 297–305, 1999

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto Thanks for pointing out the relativistic effect.  I'm trying to read more about it starting with "Relativistic quantum chemistry: The electrons and the nodes" http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed045p558 and "Contour diagrams for relativistic orbitals" http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed046p678

Comment: Nice finds. The last article is actually what I read a couple of years ago! "Pseudo-node" is in fact the term I meant to say before. I suppose that technically means you have your answer, though the non-relativistic picture is still of interest.

Answer (score 4):

My answer to this question is the following. Nodes can happen for highly excited states, whose average distances are typically much larger than the Bohr radius. Consider Na, Cs etc, which have one outermost shell electron. When the outermost shell electron is highly excited, the case is not much different from that of a hydrogen atom (i.e. the indistinguishability of electrons may be ignored when electrons are well separated.) Thus there can be nodes in these highly excited states.

A more non-trivial question is, whether the *total* electron density can have nodes for the *ground state*. I tend to think that it's not possible. My following naive, sketchy explanation may be seriously wrong. For a second-order eigenvalue problem, we have the sturm theorem (?; in doubt), which guarantees that the roots of successive states occur in an interlacing manner. That means, where state $i$ has a node at $r_i$, state $i+1$ cannot have a node at $r_i$. Thus the density, which is equal to the sum of square of wave function of all the occupied states, cannot be zero at one point. We have a similar second-order eigenvalue problem for each angular momentum $l$, and so the argument goes.

The above too sketchy, so let's formalise it a bit based on the one-particle approximation. The total ground-state electron density is proportional to $ \sum_{\{n,l, m, s\}; \textrm{occupied}}|\psi_{nlm}(r)|^2 |Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi)|^2$. Here $s$ is for the spin, $n$ labels the energy state (1 for ground, 2 for first excited, etc), and the sum is over all occupied states. Note that in order for the electronic density to be zero at $r_0$, each term has to vanish at $r_0$. But remember that for $l=0$, $m=0$, the $n=1$ radial wave function $\psi_{100}(r)$ can have no node, and $Y_{00}$ is a constant, which means the term $\psi_{100}(r)Y_{00}$ can vanish nowhere in space. This state **has** to be occupied in the ground state.

Comment: Indeed as I stated in one of my comments to the original question: You are right in thinking that the ground state of an atom should not show any nodes. There is even a strict proof for this: According to Courant's nodal line theorem the eigenfunction corresponding to the lowest eigenvalue cannot have any nodes (except the trivial one at infinity).

Answer (score 2):

There is a proof of node for the triplet-S state of helium in [What Do We Know About Wavefunction Nodes?](https://books.google.com/books?id=os3UCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&dq=helium%20atom%20nodes&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8_d7L4sbPAhUBdD4KHdACDhw4ChDoAQgqMAM#v=onepage&q=helium%20atom%20nodes&f=false) *Recent Advances in Computational Chemistry* vol. 2.  (alternative [link to preprint version](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0106062)):

The wavefunction can be written as a function of only 3 coordinates: the distance ($r_1$) of the first electron from the nucleus, the distance ($r_2$) of the second electron from the nucleus, and the distance ($r_{12}$) between the electrons.

$\Psi = \Psi(r_1, r_2, r_{12})$

by the Pauli exclusion principle:

$\Psi(r_1, r_2, r_{12}) = -\Psi(r_2, r_1, r_{12})$

Then, suppose both electrons are the same distance ($r$) from the nucleus, but not necessarily at the same point:

$\Psi(r, r, r_{12}) = -\Psi(r, r, r_{12})$

Therefore,

$\Psi(r, r, r_{12}) = 0$

In other words, there is a node defined by $r_1 = r_2$.

The two electrons can never be the same distance from the nucleus.

The reference goes on to say that in 6-dimensional space, the node is a 5-dimensional hypersurface.