# Benzene from cyclopropane-1,2,3-triyltrimethanol in acidic medium

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, alcohols

What is the mechanism of the conversion of cyclopropane-1,2,3-triyltrimethanol to benzene in in acidic medium?

[image: conversion of cyclopropane-1,2,3-triyltrimethanol to benzene in in acidic medium]

After performing E1 thrice I was expecting 1,2,3-trimethylidenecyclopropane to form instead:

[image: 1,2,3-trimethylidenecyclopropane]

I know it's highly strained, but I couldn't adopt any other pathway to reach any other product. Is the triene product not formed at all? If cyclopropane-1,2,3-trione can exist, I think even the triene product can.

This reaction is from my exercise book, couldn't find it on [OrgSyn](http://orgsyn.org).

Comment: This reaction does not show up in Scifinder. The triol is known though: Org Lett, 2007, 9, 2617 DOI:10.1021/ol070707r

Comment: No hits on Reaxys either. I strongly doubt it is real.

Answer (score 13):

I have not written the steps for carbocation formation, simple dehydration.[image]

Comment: The mechanism is plausible, but I think it is still important to emphasise that this reaction is not known. There are zero reports of anybody getting benzene by treating the starting material with acid. Probably somebody made it up.

Comment: @ortho With a little foresight into this whole JEE business, you'll know that it's almost *definitely* made up ;-)

Comment: It looks nice on the paper.

Comment: Hey primary cations are too unstable.

Comment: @Tech kidda: They may be unstable but that doesn't mean they don't form. I also checked Chem. Absts. NADA!

Comment: The diene could very well lose hydrogen and become aromatic; that would be favourable to ring cation I think.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, in the second step there should be migration of Hydrogen to form a 3° carbocation and then the double bond will form between the two methanol branches.This will entirely change the product but as per rule the 1° cation has to be further stabilized by shifting of hydrogen.