# Confusion regarding dehydration of 1° alcohols

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols, elimination

My lecturer told me that 2° and 3° alcohols prefer to dehydrate through E-1 mechanism. On the other hand, 1° alcohols tend to prefer the E-2 mechanism, which does not involve the formation of a carbocation intermediate, and thus rues out scope for rearrangement.

This is backed by online sources:

> **Primary alcohols** undergo **bimolecular elimination** (E2 mechanism) while **secondary and tertiary** alcohols undergo **unimolecular elimination** (E1 mechanism). [Source](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_(Wade)/14%3A_Reactions_of_Alcohols/14.04%3A_Dehydration_Reactions_of_Alcohols#:%7E:text=Secondary%20and%20tertiary%20alcohols%20dehydrate,carbocation%20as%20the%20reaction%20intermediate.)

Another site tells me:

> You will find two versions of the mechanism for the dehydration of primary alcohols on the web and in various textbooks.
>
> One of these is exactly the same as the mechanism for the reaction involving propan-2-ol and other secondary or tertiary alcohols (known technically as an E1 mechanism), but the other is different (known as an E2 mechanism).
>
> The more **reliable sources give the E2 mechanism** for the dehydration of primary alcohols including ethanol. I am going to treat this as the "correct" version, and have added a note as to why I think is better following the mechanism. [Sourced from chemguide](https://www.chemguide.co.uk/mechanisms/elim/elimtt.html).

The note goes on to read:

> [...]you would get a primary carbocation formed, CH3CH2+, but this is much less stable than a secondary or tertiary carbocation. That would lead to a **very high activation energy** for the reaction.
> The alternative mechanism avoids the formation of the carbocation, and so avoids the high activation energy.

Hence my first question:

> What should be the preferred mechanism?

But wait a minute. That wasn't my original question.

My original question is derived from this other post: [Benzene from cyclopropane-1,2,3-triyltrimethanol in acidic medium](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/99257/benzene-from-cyclopropane-1-2-3-triyltrimethanol-in-acidic-medium). The comments seem to suggest that this reaction is not known, while another writes that *"I strongly doubt it is real"*.

The top voted answer suggests the formation of a carbocation intermediate leading to ring expansion. And here's where my questions coalesce. The above mentioned compound consists of three $1° OH^-$ groups. This seems to suggest that an E-2 elimination reaction should occur, which rules out the possibility of rearrangement, or for that matter, ring expansion.

**TL, DR;**

> 1. What should be the preferred mechanism for 1°, 2° and 3° alcohols?
> 2. If the mechanism for 1° is E-2, why should carbocation induced ring expansion occur in the dehydration of cyclopropane-1,2,3-triyltrimethanol?

Comment: I couldn't find a suitable image for the aforementioned compound; if someone does, be so kind as to edit it in.

Comment: That's a stabilized primary cation. It's debatable if it's even a primary cation at all, since the system would be homo-allylic.

Comment: @Zhe so is the answer mentioned in the other post is correct? From what I could gather, there was quite a bit of discrepancy.

Comment: The question is kind of moot because it's a hypothetical reaction. But as proposed, it would not violate the rule.