# Cyclobutylamine with sodium nitrite in dilute HCl

Tags: organic-chemistry

What are the products formed in the reaction of cyclobutylamine with $\ce{NaNO2}$ and $\ce{HCl}$?

I thought the answer was only cyclobutanol. But the answer given says the product contains cyclopropyl carbinol as well. How does the second product form?

This is basically a diazotization reaction which results in  the conversion of $\ce{- NH2}$ to $\ce{- N2^+Cl-}$ which is a good leaving group. Then water molecules will attack the carbon containing the leaving group. Is the reaction $\rm{S_N1}$ or $\rm{S_N2}$?

Comment: The water is attacking the carbon next to the one that has the diazonium cation on it, this leads to a bond migration and subsequent loss of nitrogen.  As to whether the reaction occurs in the order described is another matter.

Comment: It is an SN1 reaction, see [this](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/28939/carbocation-rearrangement-due-to-ring-strain-and-back-bonding) earlier answer.

Comment: @ron why does the nucleophilic attack a carbon that does not contain a leaving group?

Comment: The initially formed cyclobutyl cation quickly equilibrates with the cyclopropyl carbinyl cation which has positive charge on the necessary carbon.

Comment: Should I mark this question as duplicate @ron ?

Comment: I think your question covers the same general ground, so yes, mark it as a duplicate.