# Stability of tertiary carbocation

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, carbocation

Our teacher told us that a carbocation connected to 3 cyclopropane rings is among the most stable carbocations. But I am unable to understand how, as resonance (the most important factor governing stability) is absent. How did other factors bring so much stability?

Comment: It is not called ‘three degree’, it is *tertiary*. Likewise, they are *secondary* and *primary* carbocations. The degree notation should have died out a long time ago.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/48264/54655

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/19090 Half-way dupe. If I vote to close it will be close-hammered because of my badge so I will leave it to others to decide if this is dupe-y enough.

Answer (score -3):

Your teacher is correct, that

> a carbocation connected to 3 cyclopropane rings is among the most stable carbocations.

This because of various electrical effects, such as:

1. The Inductive Effect
2. Resonance
3. The Mesomeric Effect
4. Electromeric Effect
5. Hyperconjugation

Here's a link for you, to study them: [Click Here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/inductive-effect-electromeric-efffect-resonance/).
Please make sure that you learn this correctly and from standard resources, in order to avoid confusion.

There may be a little confusion between mesomeric effect and resonance effect, so here's another link just to avoid confusion. : [refer to the answer by Maria Dar](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-mesomeric-effect-and-a-resonance?share=1)

Please, do ask your teacher to help you understand this topic better :-)

Comment: To state the blooming obvious, only one of those effects has anything to do with cyclopropylmethyl carbocations. Further, are you affiliated with that study link site because it may be considered spammy.

Comment: It is spammy as it is really bizarre to start speaking of electronic effects in chemical reactions than afterwards recalling what molecules are :) But the user invite to study standard resources, this is also true