# Why is cyclopropyl carbanion more stable than propyl carbanion

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons

A problem was given in which the order of rate of decarboxylation was asked for the compounds cyclopropane carboxylic acid and and butanoic acid. It's known that the rate here depends on the stability of carbanion intermediate formed during the reaction. The answer was given that the rate of cyclopropane carboxylic acid is higher than that of butanoic acid which means that cyclopropyl carbanion is more stable than propyl carbanion but I'm unable to figure out why? Please help me here. (Here I saw the +I effect on the cyclopropyl carbanion due to 2 methyl groups and, +I effect of ethyl group on propyl carbanion but then too couldn't conclude the exact reason for such an answer.)

Comment: Cyclopropyl ring has greater electronegativity than a normal alkyl chain carbanion. Because of this, the negative charge gets pulled, hence resulting in stability.

Comment: do you have a reference for this?

Comment: Did you search this site first? https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67704/why-is-cyclopropane-more-acidic-than-propane